# Why does assigning a default to a dataclass field, make it into a class attribute?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

When you add a field to a python dataclass, it will become a required argument for `__init__` and it will be an instance attribute. But when you add a default value to a field it becomes a class attribute.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class A:
    foo: int
    bar: int = 0

>>> A.foo
AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute 'foo'
>>> A.bar
0
```

Why this difference between `foo` and `bar`?
Dataclass prevents you from setting mutable defaults, so it will not become a problem in practice, but I was curious about this behaviour, which was unexpected for me.

Comment: There is no difference. If you remove the dataclass decorator, the code will behave in exactly the same way. What other behaviour were you expecting?

Comment: @ekhumoro, I was expecting `bar` to be an instance attribute and not a class attribute. The difference I'm asking about is the difference between `foo` and `bar` (question edited)

Comment: That changes nothing. Using a dataclass decorator creates a normal Python class. If you try to access an attribute that doesn't exist, an attribute-error will be raised. What other behaviour were you expecting?

Comment: @ekhumoro it's at least a little weird how it behaves---bar is a class attr that can be mutated, but when you create a new instance, the instance will have an instance variable that shadows the class attr with the initial value provided at definition time---not the mutated version. I.e., the dataclass creates both instance and class attrs with the same name when you provide a default.

Comment: I'm not surprised that `A.foo` gives an AttributeError, I'm surprised that `A.bar` doesn't. Setting a field without default makes an instance attribute. Why does adding a default value makes a class attribute?

Comment: @mahkitah Because that's how *normal classes* behave. Consider this code: `class A: bar = 0; a = A(); a.bar = 1; print(A.bar)`. It would be pretty weird if the output of this was `1`, right? What would be the justification for a dataclass behaving any differently? The normal expectation is that instance attributes always override class attributes, and that the original default value remains part of the class definition.

Comment: @alkasm It's not weird. It works that way to avoid well-known issues with mutable defaults (see: e.g. [PEP-557](https://peps.python.org/pep-0557/#mutable-default-values)).

Comment: @ekhumoro "_What would be the justification for a dataclass behaving any differently?_" I'd say the justification would be consistent behaviour between fields with and without default, but this would be at the cost of inconsistency with normal class behaviour. So I understand the decision (now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got things backward. Setting a field default doesn't make it a class attribute. *Setting a class attribute*, and annotating it, causes the `@dataclass` decorator to process that attribute as the default value of the field with that name.

When you write

```
@dataclass
class A:
    foo: int
    bar: int = 0
```

what `bar: int = 0` *means* is that you're creating a class attribute named `bar` with value `0`, and creating an annotation of `int` for that attribute.

`@dataclass` will look at that and generate an `__init__` that sets `bar` to `0` on an instance if no other value is provided, so there will be a `bar` instance attribute on instances you create. But the class attribute is still there too.

There's a bit more to it than this, because if you create field objects:

```
@dataclass
class A:
    foo: int = field()
    bar: int = field(default=0)
```

this is still setting class attributes, but `@dataclass` won't just leave the field objects there. A field with no default will be deleted from the class attributes, while a field with a default will be replaced with its default value. So `@dataclass` doesn't quite just leave all your class attributes there. It goes to deliberate effort to make sure defaults are class attributes, even in cases with `field` where they wouldn't be.

Comment: Is the first example just a syntactic simplification of the second example, or do they behave differently under the hood (while still giving the same result)?

Comment: @mahkitah: They behave differently under the hood, but produce equivalent dataclasses.

Comment: The underlying behaviour is almost identical. In both cases, the decorator will iterate over the class annotations and use `getattr` to find a default (or use a sentinel instead). If the default isn't already a field object, it is simply replaced by `field(default=default)`. Either way, the eventual result is the same (i.e. a normal python class).